# Passing parameter into WCF metadata

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I have a WCF service with a class that implements `IContractBehavior` and `IWsdlExportExtension` that generates a WSDL with a user's allowed operations and excludes operations and types they do not have access to.

The limitation of this is however is that for each user,  I have to manually change which user I am generating the WSDL for.

I'd like to fix this limitation by passing in the user as part of the request for the metadata for example.

- `localhost/service.svc?user=me`
  or
- `localhost:9766/service.svc?singleWsdl&user=me`

Alternatively I could use `svcutil` would also work as long as the resulting WSDL is flattened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by doing the following

- I host the service in console application.
- I added an endpoint with the  `IContractBehavior` added to it, passing in the  desired parameter into the `IContractBehavior` class.
- After the service is open, I use WsdlExporter to export the `Metatadaset`
- Finally I use    the WsdlHelper to generate the Wsdl file as
  described here
  http://www.shulerent.com/2013/03/14/generating-a-single-flattened-wsdl-from-an-existing-wcf-service/

The code

```
const string BASE_ADDRESS = 
"http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/CalcService";
var uri = new Uri(BASE_ADDRESS);
var user = "userName";

using (var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Calc), uri))
{
  var exporter = new WsdlExporter();
  var endpoint = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalc),
  new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
  endpoint.Contract.Behaviors.Add(new
  RestrictedOperationsWsdlExportExtensionAttribute(user));
  serviceHost.Open();
  Console.WriteLine("The service is ready: " + user);
  exporter.ExportEndpoint(endpoint);
  if (exporter.Errors.Count == 0)
  {
    var metadataSet = exporter.GetGeneratedMetadata();
    var asy= Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(WsdlExporter));
    var t = asy.GetType("System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlHelper",
      true);
    var method = t.GetMethod("GetSingleWsdl", 
      System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public 
      | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
    var serviceDescription =
      method.Invoke(null, new object[] {metadataSet})
      as System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription;
    if (serviceDescription != null)
    {
      serviceDescription.Name = "Calc";
      serviceDescription.Write(user + ".wsdl");
    }
  }
}
```